# Cannot get element in iframe which was inserted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

I insert an iframe using iquery from the top level.

```
 var url = //localhost/t1.php  ; 
 $('#div_display').html("<iframe style='width:880px;height:1000px; id='sq_iframe' src='" +url+  "'></iframe>");
```

But I cannot get the height of a div_xx inside the iframe when I tried to change its height.

```
   var  oldheight=  $("#sq_iframe").contents().find("#div_xx").height() ; 
   alert( oldheight) ;
   $("#sq_iframe").contents().find("#div_xx").height('500') ;
```

What is the problem here, experts?

Comment: your Iframe domain is same as ur domain ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `css()` to set styles to the div

Try this

```
$("#sq_iframe").contents().find("#div_xx").css('height','500px') ;
```

OR

```
$("#sq_iframe").contents().find("#div_xx").height(500) ;
```

Get Height of Div Inside Iframe

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#frameDemo" ).on('load', function() { 
        var mydiv = $(this).contents().find("div");
        var h     = mydiv.height();
        alert(h);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to get oldheight first. But I could not get the oldheight ?

Comment: I am getting null as the height? Since I insert iframe in a div, I am wondering that would be a problem for find the element? 
 $('#div_display').html("<iframe style='width:880px;height:1000px; id='sq_iframe' src='" +url+  "'></iframe>");

Comment: use `$('#div_display').append()`